# Why does apt package manager on ubuntu 22.04 install a very old version of nodejs(16)

Tags: nodejs

GNU nano 6.2                  /etc/apt/sources.list                     M
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted
I upgraded to 22.04 because I wanted to install a higher version of nodejs through apt package manager but it installed the same old version that 21.04 would install, 16 There aren't any files with node in their names in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory and this is my /etc/apt/sources.list file

deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted #Ad>
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted # auto generated by >
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe # a>
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe #>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Yes it does but still leaves me feeling 22.04 should install a higher version of nodejs than 21.04 did They both install 16 I upgraded my release because I thought the jammy repos would have a higher nodejs version but I guess I was just wrong

Comment: More volunteers doing packaging = newer software in Debian and Ubuntu repositories. It's that simple. Ubuntu is community-driven.